# Unix - Need to display directory last modified time

Tags: linux, unix, hp-ux

need to display the directory's timestamp - Last modified time of the directory

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple command: ls -la

Comment: `ls -ld .` limits the output to just the directory itself.  Megan5's answer will give you a line for every file in the directory.